# Conversion Moneda dentro de Condición SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta donde estoy haciendo una condición y el resultado me lo convierta a formato moneda, pero me sale el siguiente error:

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '$3,800.00' to data type int.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
SELECT
 IIF ((SUM(SUM(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO)) OVER (ORDER BY A.POSTURA ASC)) <= B.MONTO_EMISION, '$' + FORMAT((SUM(SUM(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO)) OVER (ORDER BY A.POSTURA ASC)),'#,0.00'),0) AS ACUM2
FROM TBITACORA A
INNER JOIN TDASHBOARD B ON A.REF = B.REF
GROUP BY A.REF, B.MONTO_EMISION
```

Alguien tiene una experiencia similar? Gracias

Comment: saca el simbolo $ que no tiene nada que hacer ahi adentro...

Comment: Gracias, quitando la concatenación del signo $ el resultado es: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '3,800.00' to data type int.

Comment: mismo tema.. hay un separador de miles que no tiene que estar... porque tenes los numeros guardados asi???

Comment: Gracias, porque lo que estoy intentando es convertir el acumulado a formato de moneda. Por supuesto que si le retiro el format me da el acumulado, el tema es que quiero convertirlo a moneda, y al tratar de hacerlo marca el error con ese separador:

Comment: '$' + FORMAT((SUM(SUM(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO)) OVER (ORDER BY A.POSTURA ASC)),'#,0.00') -> Así es como lo trato de convertir y no me funciona

Comment: Monto_solicitado que tiene adentro, un numero, o un varchar con formato?

Comment: Gracias, Contiene numero de tipo float.

Comment: cambia esto: ,0) por ,'0')

Comment: Perfecto! Funciona de esta manera. Gracias, cerrado

Comment: no.. no esta cerrado.. entendes porque escribi lo que escribi y cual era el problema????

Comment: Al tener ,0) por ,0) (Sin las comillas marca: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '$3,800.00' to data type int. Al colocarle las comillas el código queda de la siguiente forma:

IIF ((SUM(SUM(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO)) OVER (ORDER BY A.POSTURA ASC)) <= B.MONTO_EMISION, '$' + FORMAT((SUM(SUM(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO)) OVER (ORDER BY A.POSTURA ASC)),'#,0.00'),'0') AS ACUM2

Lo cual significa que si el acumulado es menor o igual a emisión coloque el acumulado y cuando no se cumple que coloque 0. Tu comentario fue colocar las comillas a 0 y funciona la sentencia.

Comment: si.. buenisimo.. pero no entendiste el error, ni porque las comillas lo solucionan, no?

Comment: Si, lo que comprendo (y me suena lógico) es por el tipo de conversión que se esta enviando a pantalla, el format concatenado con un signo '$' estamos enviando un valor de tipo varchar, por lo tanto al no cumplirse tiene que ser un tipo de valor similar.

Comment: exacto!!! la columna no puede tener varchar e int al mismo tiempo.. perfecto.. ahora explica todo en una linda respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Gracias @gbianchi por el apoyo. La solución fue la siguiente:

```
IIF ((SUM(SUM(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO)) OVER (ORDER BY A.POSTURA ASC)) <= B.MONTO_EMISION, '$' + FORMAT((SUM(SUM(A.MONTO_SOLICITADO)) OVER (ORDER BY A.POSTURA ASC)),'#,0.00'),'0') AS ACUM2
```

Donde se agrega comillas al **,'0')** ya que como bien lo explica la columna no puede tener varchar e int al mismo tiempo. Ocasionando el error al intentar mostrar la conversión con el format y al no cumplirse enviar un int (0). Solucionado